# refactor a functionwich makes a form

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I got a working function, but i think it should become a lot smaller and better but i aint seeing it. can someone help me improve this function make it better:

I am making a new li-item in a unordered list. in there there is omse info in 3 divisions who get a class making them float left to eachother.

this is the code i used, its all listed out, it can probly be make a lot better, and i hope to learn to refactor my code more, so help is apriciated.

```
// making new li item inn <ul>
function addproduction(){
  // getting info from form
  var startdatum_form = document.getElementById('startdatum').value;
  var uren_form  = document.getElementById('uren').value;
  var ordernummer_form  = document.getElementById('ordernummer').value;

  // new li element
  var newli = document.createElement('li');
  newli.setAttribute('class', 'ui-state-default');

  var div1 = document.createElement('div');
  div1.setAttribute('class', 'div1');
    var sortableicon = document.createElement('span');
    sortableicon.setAttribute('class', 'ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s');

    // count current li elements in UL:
      var number = 0;
      var ullist = document.getElementById('sortable');
      for(i=0;i< ullist.childNodes.length;i++){
          if(ullist.childNodes[i].nodeName=='LI'){
              number++;
          }
      }
  newli.setAttribute('id', 'p'+(number+1));


    // text node (item x)
    var nrText = document.createTextNode('Item ' + (number+1));
    div1.appendChild(sortableicon)
    div1.appendChild(nrText);
  var div2 = document.createElement('div');
  div2.setAttribute('class', 'div1');
        var indiv1 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Title'));
        var indiv2 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Start'));
        var indiv3 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('End'));
        var indiv4 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv4.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Uren'));
            div2.appendChild(indiv1);
            div2.appendChild(indiv2);
            div2.appendChild(indiv3);
            div2.appendChild(indiv4);
  var div3 = document.createElement('div');
  div3.setAttribute('class', 'div3');
        var indiv5 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ordernummer_form));
        var indiv6 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv6.appendChild(document.createTextNode(startdatum_form));
        var indiv7 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv7.appendChild(document.createTextNode('end'));
        var indiv8 = document.createElement('div');
        indiv8.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uren_form));
            div3.appendChild(indiv5);
            div3.appendChild(indiv6);
            div3.appendChild(indiv7);
            div3.appendChild(indiv8);

    newli.appendChild(div1);
    newli.appendChild(div2);
    newli.appendChild(div3);

    // add new production to list
    document.getElementById('sortable').appendChild(newli);
    saveNewEntry( (number+1), ordernummer_form, startdatum_form, uren_form );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by I am not seeing it? Refactoring starts with putting code that is used a lot with just a different variable into a function that takes an argument. You have a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: I dont see how i would be able to refactor, i need to know how i be doing it, example so i can do it myself next time. I want to improve myself next time

Answer (score 0):

A small example which could be applied to other parts of your code as well

```
  var startdatum_form = document.getElementById('startdatum').value;
  var uren_form  = document.getElementById('uren').value;
  var ordernummer_form  = document.getElementById('ordernummer').value;
```

could be

```
var startdatum_form   = get_value('startdatum');
var uren_form         = get_value('uren');
var ordernummer_form  = get_value('ordernummer');

function get_value( field ) {
  return document.getElementById(field).value;
}
```